# Selective Git pull request

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I'm new to git and I'm trying to collaborate on a Github project.  I forked a project, added features, and ported to Android for my own needs.  The added features are desired in the base project, but not the android-related files.  What's the procedure to make a pull request without the files I committed to my own fork that are only related to android development?

I would think this would be a common task given ide preferences and such, but amazingly I can find very little on this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is to use branches.

- In your fork (the local clone of your fork), create a branch from the point where you forked the original project. Typically you do this by creating an remote called *upstream* and then branching from *upstream/master*.
- Name this branch something like *featureA*, describing what you want to accomplish.
- Make your feature changes in this branch.
- Push the branch to your fork (*origin*).
- Create the pull request from this branch. It should only have the changes for this feature, not your Android changes.

You can do your Android changes in another branch in your fork. This way, the changes stay separate.

If you want your *featureA* changes in your fork, merge the *featureA* branch into your fork's *master*.

Whenever you do a Pull Request to another project, use a branch, and make sure that the branch is based on the current state of the upstream repo that you forked - otherwise you will have lots of unwanted changes in there.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, this was actually what I was starting to lean towards.  To elaborate: I'd work in branchAndroid and selectively commit code related changes to branchFeature and branchAndroid would be the complete code base I work on?  Then PR would be from branchFeature.

Comment: Essentially yes. Just make sure that _branchFeature_ is based off the master or develop branch of the upstream project.

Comment: That worked like a charm.  It was a little daunting at first to switch back and forth between the branches and merging, but I can't believe how easy it was to manage in the end.  Thanks a lot, would have made many failed attempts without the advice.